Remove e-mail address with whitespaces
I am working with call centre transcripts. In an ideal case the speech-to-text software will transcribe an e-mail as follows: maya.lucco@proton.me. This will not always be the case. So I am looking at a regular expression (RegEx) solution that accommodates whitespaces in the e-mail address, e.g. maya lucco@proton.me or maya.lucco @proton.me or maya-lucco@pro ton.me
I have unsuccessfully tried to extend this solution with regex101. Compiling a re object (pattern) as suggested in this solution seems overly complex for the task. I looked at the posts on validating e-mail addresses but they describe a different issue. Below my code so far:
import re 

#creating some data 
test = ['some random text maya @ proton.me with some more text maya+lucco@proton.me',
        'maya-lucco@proton.me with another address maya_lucco@proton.me',
        'some text maya.lucco @proton.me with some more bla maya.lucco@proton.me',
        'maya-lucco_@proton.me more text maya@ proton.me '
        ]
        
test = pd.DataFrame(test, columns = ['words'])

#creating a function because I like to add some other data cleaning to it later on
def anonymiseEmail(text):
    
    text = str(text) #make text as string variable
    text = text.strip() #remove any leading, and trailing whitespaces
    text = re.sub(r'\S*@\S*\s?', '{e-mail}', text) #remove e-mail address
    
    return text

# applying the function
test['noEmail'] = test.words.apply(anonymiseEmail)

#checking the results
print(test.noEmail[0])

Output: some random text maya {e-mail}proton.me with some more text {e-mail}

The first e-mail address does not get fully deleted. The firstname Maya remains. This is a problem for the project.
How can the code be extended so that the whole e-mail address, regardless of how many whitespaces it has, be replaced with a placed holder or deleted?
Up-date following the comments:
I have looked into RegEx lookahead and lookbehind, i.e. (?=@)  and (?<=@) but can't seem to make it match the word(s) that proceed or succeed the @-sign. I am looking at a code snippet Wiktor Stribiżew kindly provided on another occasion \b(?:Dear|H(?:ello|i))(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]\w*(?:[’'-]\w+)*\.?)+''', '', text and thought I could up-date it to (?i)\b(?<=@)(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]\w*(?:[’'-]\w+)*\.?)+ 
but it doesn't match any e-mail address according to regex101. Maybe the code snippet (?i)\b(?<=@) (or any other RegEx) can be modified to match the proceeding and/or succeeding word(s)?
Another possible solution that comes to my mind is to select the 5 words before and after the @-sign, put them in a separate variable, check if there are any whitespaces 4 letters/characters before and after the @-sign. If yes, put them in a queue for a manual check. What concerns me with this solution is a) computing power, b) technical implementation and c) general feasibility. But I thought I'd share it in the spirit of trying to find a solution.

If you have "random text maya @ proton.me", how will you know if the email is maya@proton.me, textmaya@proton.me, or randomtextmaya@proton.me? Do you have a list of known email addresses to compare against?

Having had to delete this question before here a note: an example does not lack reproducibility because the name in the example is is female, e.g. Maya, instead of John. I thought this was a old news these days...

@Jack good question. Thought about this too but then thought maybe someone here had an idea how to solve this.
Btw the other comment I made has nothing to do with yours. ;-)

@Jack Good idea with the list. Two concerns I see i) the CRM from where I would get the list is outdated or lacks the data  ii) I can't get access to the data because of internal data privacy regulations.

The problem is unsolveable.  In the sentence "my email is joe @ sample.com", how can you possibly know that it shouldn't be "myemailisjoe@sample.com"?

You'd probably be better off sending the original audio to an NLP model trained to identify and record email addresses heard in the conversation - as @TimRoberts pointed out there's no pure regex way to know where the regular copy stops and the space separated email begins

Thanks for all the suggestions. Just up-dated the post with some ideas taking the @-sign as a starting point to identify e-mail addresses.

@jmcgriz good idea. stanza works best for German text data but RegEx outperforms it for the tasks I have to do. Tested several "NLP models" including stanza a couple of weeks ago. Know my way round there :-) Or did you mean train my own NLP model for the e-mail task?

On a general note, I know this post is pushing it. But I have to try. Working with personally identifiable and sensitive data. So the 60% accuracy the stanza achieves in NER in German to identify street names and towns is not good enough. That is why I turned to RegEx. I appreciate your thoughts. Thanks!

"an example does not lack reproducibility because the name in the example is is female, e.g. Maya, instead of John." - nobody supposed such a thing; the feedback you're getting is completely unrelated to anything to do with gender; and the fact that you might imagine so is... not promising. The problem is still fundamentally intractable, and we have high standards for questions here because this is not a discussion forum; we don't exist to solve the OP's problem, but to provide answers to focused, searchable questions that can help everyone.

@KarlKnechtel I also don’t understand the relevance of that comment. And to which comments of the old deleted post this should refer to.

Ah, I see. The reason the email address in the deleted post was edited, is because it appeared to be a genuine one. We don't want questions to include email addresses that could inadvertently get unwanted mail (particularly spam) sent to someone else. (similarly, the reason for wondering whether you were looking for a Pandas solution, is because the example used test = pd.DataFrame(test, columns = ['words']). It's important to remove irrelevant details from examples, even if that makes it look different from your actual code; see [mre] to understand.

Figuring out how many spaces to ignore after @ is already hard and ambiguous. But the part before the @ can basically be anything. One could have an own domain using a unique identifier for each service registered to, it could be a fictional name, a place, a phrase. So you would need to guess based on the context if the space shouldn’t be there. This is something trained language models might be good at.

an example does not lack reproducibility because the name in the example is is female, e.g. Maya not sure how the gender of the name is relevant for the problem. Besides that Maya - even if probably not likely - can also be a male name, or it could also be a surename, and there are cultures where the order might be surename.given-name@….

Separately, deleting your first question and then asking again with the same flaws is disruptive and potentially harmful for your own experience (there are penalties if you do that repeatedly). I wish I could understand what caused you to think I was sabotaging your asking experience (or how you thought posting five comments in rapid succession was somehow okay, while you were apparently objecting to me posting one edit and one comment) but perhaps that's a topic for [meta].

Just to spell this out, the reason I anonymized your original post, like @KarlKnechtel notes, had nothing to do with the perceived gender of the owner of the address. I started to replace it with firstname.lastname@example.int but it came out too abstract, so I used the most generic name I could come up with. jane.smith would work fine instead of john.smith; sorry if that change riled your sensibilities.

Here's a tweaked regular expression for recognising the email addresses like maya @ proton.me.
import pandas as pd

def anonymiseEmail(text):
    email_regex = r"\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+\s*@\s*[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b"
    return re.sub(email_regex, "{e-mail}", str(text).strip())


lines = [
    "some random text maya @ proton.me with some more text maya+lucco@proton.me",
    "maya-lucco@proton.me with another address maya_lucco@proton.me",
    "some text maya.lucco @proton.me with some more bla maya.lucco@proton.me",
    "maya-lucco_@proton.me more text maya@ proton.me "
    ]

sample = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Lines"], data=lines)
sample["NoEmail"] = sample.Lines.apply(anonymiseEmail)

print(sample.NoEmail)

Output:
0    some random text {e-mail} with some more text ...
1               {e-mail} with another address {e-mail}
2       some text {e-mail} with some more bla {e-mail}
3                          {e-mail} more text {e-mail}
Name: NoEmail, dtype: object


The OP's example doesn't bear this out, but in reality, a longer transcript may well contain additional clues as to what the person's real name might be, and so that knowledge might help you prefer "maya@something" or "maya.lucco@something" (with various punctuation between the names, or none, as well as variations like "luccom@something" or "mlucco@something" or "mayal@something" etc) over "randomtextmaya@something" etc.

Thanks for taking the time to provide a solution. It is better than existing solutions I found on SO and linked to in my post. Just for completeness for other readers, this solution will not work on maya@ proton .me. For maya .lucca@ proton.me it will only delete .lucca@ proton.me. maya will remain. BUT it cleans out more e-mail addresses than previous code.
